# Windows based Azure Container Instance (ACI) - VNet integration

Tags: azure-container-instances

I heard only linux ACI's can be integrated to VNet .

Can windows OS based Azure Container Instance be integrated to VNet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, See the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#other-limitations):

> Currently, only Linux containers are supported in a container group
> deployed to a virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

It's announced that support for Windows containers with VNET integration is coming early 2021. Source [Azure Container Instances (ACI) under the hood | Azure Friday](https://youtu.be/giQLmxMKAKE?t=412)

Answer (score 0):

vNet deployment is GA for both Linux and Windows containers now:

> Container group deployment to a virtual network is generally available for Linux and Windows containers, in most regions where Azure Container Instances is available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).